# How to make .off file

Tags: 3d, raytracing

I basically know how to make a .off file because our teacher gave us some but the problem is that I wanted to created one myself, and I think that the order of the triangles forming my object are not right.

```
OFF
8 12 0
1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
-1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
-1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
1.000000 0.999999 1.000000
0.999999 -1.000001 1.000000
-1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
-1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
3 3 0 1
3 3 2 1
3 4 0 1
3 4 5 1
3 7 4 5
3 7 6 5
3 2 1 5
3 2 6 5
3 7 3 2
3 7 6 2
3 3 0 4
3 3 7 4
```

Does someone know an application which makes .off automatically from the scene that we made ?

Answer (score 0):

Meshlab[1] is able to export files in .off format.

[1] http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/